# ImportError when execute script from command line

Tags: python, eclipse, command-line, sys

When executing script from command line, I got the following error

> ImportError: No module named SubPackage3.MyClass

My package is structured as

> TopLevelPackage
>
> ..SubPackage1
>
> ..SubPackage2
>
> ..SubPackage3
>
> ..__init_.py
>
> ..README.md
>
> python (/usr/bin/python)

From other posts it seems that the problem is that the system does not recognize the path to SubPackage3. I have a separate __init_.py in each of the SubPackage, and print(sys.path) gave me

> /home/shaunz/workspace/TopLevelPackage/SubPackage1
>
> /home/shaunz/workspace/TopLevelPackage
>
> /usr/lib/python2.7
>
> ....

Notice that only Package 1 is in the list of paths recognized. Any idea why this may be the case? And how do I change it?
I'm trying to run a module in SubPackage2. I'm using Eclipse.
Thanks

Comment: is `MyClass.py` inside subpackage3 ? You have not included wha `MyClass` is and where it is.

Comment: You wrote you have an ``__init_.py``, I'm not sure if this was just a typo in the question, but it whould be ``__init__.py`` (double underscores). I'm still missing some context though, where did you define ``MyClass``?

Comment: it's not a typo, somehow this website treats double underscores on both side of init as a signal to format "init", the file was auto generated by Eclipse. And MyClass is a class defined in a module under SubPackage3.